# Why is high molar molar mass a requirement of good primary standards for volumetric analysis?

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry, titration

I have been taught that using primary standards with a relatively high molar mass will reduce the error between the equivalence point and the end point during titration. However, I am unsure as to why this is the case.

It would be great if someone could point out to me what the purpose of using primary standards with a high molecular mass is.

Comment: The larger the sample, the less chance for an introduced impurity to affect it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I see it other way around: for the same mass of the probe, the higher the molar mass, the smaller is the amount, so impurities are actually going to interfere more IMO.

Comment: @andselisk You can likely afford to buy a higher quality standard (or spend a bit more time purifying it), but not to buy a more precise scale.

Comment: @Karl A decent lab balance is a one-time investment, whereas a set of HQ-standards for the lab performing a wide range of analyses might cost a fortune. But that's not at all what I was commenting about.

Comment: @andselisk Can`t argue much with that: I just checked the prices, and a good scale with a hundred gram scale and ten microgram resolution goes for just 2k€ today, including taxes. In the end you just have to do the math and compare the Mw and purity (and prices) of different standards in combination with the scale you have and/or want to buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This practice is done in analytical chemistry in order to minimize the relative weighing error on the balance. Preferring a larger formula weight for a primary standard has nothing to do with impurity levels. We have to start with the highest purity standard.

For example, you wish to prepare a 0.010 M solution of oxalic acid dihydrate in 1 L flask. Its formula weight is  ‎126.07 g/mol. You need to weigh out 1.2607 grams of the acid on the balance. Imagine the balance has a small constant error, the relative error in weighing is smaller for a larger formula weight compound as compared to a smaller formula weight standard for the same concentration. Imagine if the molecular weight of oxalic acid were 60 g/mol, how much do you need to weigh out?